# How to solve "Jackson – Bidirectional Relationships" when object refernce to itself

Tags: spring, rest, jackson

I'm facing the "Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)" error
and following this manual: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion I tried to solve it in my case but it seems different cause in my case the object is pointing to itself.

I mean, I have this object:

```
public class PRBOperatorId implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public PRBOperatorType type = null;

public PRBOperatorId parentId = null;

public PRBOperatorId childId = null;

public String name = null;
public String[] formats = null;
public String description = null;
public String[] examples = null;
public String returnedFormat = null;
public String comments = null;
```

And it's being used by a service to get all Operators of the root Operator using a recursive method:

```
@Override
public PRBOperatorId[] getAllChildren() {
    LinkedList<PRBOperatorId> list = new LinkedList<PRBOperatorId>();
    return getAllChildrenRec(operatorsRoot.getId(), list).toArray(new PRBOperatorId[list.size()]);
}

public Collection<PRBOperatorId> getAllChildrenRec(PRBOperatorId rootId, LinkedList<PRBOperatorId> childrenIds) {
    try {......
```

I'm not mapping a DB tables by java objects (I don't really have a one-to-many relation between objects), I'm just trying to create a Spring rest controller over the logic I have in the service.

How can I solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tell Jackson how to identify Objects? because if you do, it has no problem handling circular references even when the object is pointing to itself.

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
      generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
      property = "name")
public static class PRBOperatorId implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public PRBOperatorId parentId = null;

    public PRBOperatorId childId = null;

    public String name = null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PRBOperatorId op = new PRBOperatorId();
    op.parentId = op;
    op.childId = op;
    op.name = "aaa";
    try {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.writeValue(System.out, op);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

output:

```
{"name":"aaa","parentId":"aaa","childId":"aaa"}
```

Comment: Actually I already tried that's approch and it worked for me already :), but thanks anyway